# How to upload a ROS package to github?

Tags: ros, github, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm completely unfamiliar with github, and in their tutorial, they only show you how to upload a file to a repository. So I was wondering how i would go about uploading a ros package?

Will it be the same thing as uploading the pacakge's files individually through the repository?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240164/how-to-upload-a-ros-package-to-github?/) by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

using github for the first time is a bit tricky. just create a repository and put a readme in it. after that on the right side you will see upload files button from there you can upload your files.

for creating sub directories you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773598/creating-folders-inside-github-com-repo-without-using-git it is really easy with this method but not efficient for large packages.

---

Originally posted by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) with karma: 73 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-07-22**:
It doesn't let me upload folders though

**Comment by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) on 2016-07-22**:
If you drag and drop that will work fine and also you can create by typing /foldername while adding a file